# Failed to switch JDK version on Mac

Tags: java

I have tried several ways to switch my JDK version on mac from 13.0.2 to 14.0.1 but all failed. 
First I typed

> /usr/libexec/java_home -V
>   and it returns:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
14.0.1, x86_64: "AdoptOpenJDK 14"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
14.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 14.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_252, x86_64:  "AdoptOpenJDK 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_211, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I then added

> export JAVA_HOME= $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14.0.1)

in the bash file, and in a new terminal I typed

> java -version

it still returns:

```
Openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Where did I do wrong?

**EDIT**
when I typed

> which java
>   It returns:

```
/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin/java
```

Comment: this seems to have lots of info https://gist.github.com/hogmoru/8e02cf826c840914a8ed93fd418ed88e

Comment: looks like my current JDK version is not in the list, how's that possible?

Comment: Is the java binary that you want before the others in the PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works for me):

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14`
```

If I try to use the fully spelled out version like you did, it doesn't work.

Comment: Now that I look closer, I realize there's something more serious going on about your setup. Like where's it picking up that v13 from?! Is `ls -l /usr/bin/java` showing the right path? (i.e. `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`)?

Comment: yes, the command shows lrwxr-xr-x  '1 root  wheel  74 Oct 21  2019 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alternatives` option to switch the version:

[image]

After that - you would see the chosen version.

Comment: Thank you, but this command returns: sudo: alternatives: command not found